# Dynamically created Select Options behave differently when called from a button vs directly in function Materialize CSS

Tags: javascript, materialize

```js
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
    var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems, {});
  });


  const container = document.getElementById("stringcontainer");
  var select = createSelect(1);
  select.addEventListener('change', hello);
  container.appendChild(select);

  function add(){

    var select1 = createSelect(2);
    select1.addEventListener('change', hello);
    container.appendChild(select1);

  }

  
  function createSelect(num){
  
    //Create array of options to be added
    var array = ["Option 1","Option 2","Option 3"];
    //Create and append select list
    var selectList = document.createElement("select");
    selectList.id = "asp"+num;
    //selectList.className = "browser-default";
    selectList.required = true;
    selectList.innerHTML += "<option disabled selected>Choose Option</option>"
    //Create and append the options
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = array[i].split(" ").join("").toLowerCase();
        option.text = array[i]; 
        selectList.appendChild(option);
    }
        return selectList;
  }
  
  function hello(){
    console.log("Added EventListener");
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@materializecss/materialize@1.1.0/dist/css/materialize.min.css">


 <div class="row">
     <div id="stringcontainer"/>
 </div><!-- CLOSE ROW -->
 
 <div class="row">
   <div class="input-field col s3">
       <button id="astring" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small" 
        onclick="add()">Add</button>
   </div>
 </div><!-- CLOSE ROW -->
  

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@materializecss/materialize@1.1.0/dist/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Called from JS as a function:

[image]

Called from a button with the same function:

[image]

The result is an invisible unstyled select when you press the button.

I'm using Materialize CSS. The eventListener is also not working properly when adding from the button also. It works for a console log but anything more complex like getSelectedValues(), it fails

I expected the Select to render the same way as the first image. Can anyone explain why this happening and offer a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you apply the css only once in the beginning by using

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
    var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems, {});
});
```

You have to do the same, each time you add a new select. So, the following should work the way you want it to.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    applyCSS();
});


const container = document.getElementById("stringcontainer");
var select = createSelect(1);
select.addEventListener('change', hello);
container.appendChild(select);

function add(){

  var select1 = createSelect(2);
  select1.addEventListener('change', hello);
  container.appendChild(select1);
  applyCSS();
}

  
function createSelect(num){
  
    //Create array of options to be added
    var array = ["Option 1","Option 2","Option 3"];
    //Create and append select list
    var selectList = document.createElement("select");
    selectList.id = "asp"+num;
    //selectList.className = "browser-default";
    selectList.required = true;
    selectList.innerHTML += "<option disabled selected>Choose Option</option>"
    //Create and append the options
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = array[i].split(" ").join("").toLowerCase();
        option.text = array[i]; 
        selectList.appendChild(option);
    }
    return selectList;
}
  
function hello(){
    console.log("Added EventListener");
}
 
function applyCSS(){
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
    var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems, {});
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@materializecss/materialize@1.1.0/dist/css/materialize.min.css">


 <div class="row">
     <div id="stringcontainer"/>
 </div><!-- CLOSE ROW -->
 
 <div class="row">
   <div class="input-field col s3">
       <button id="astring" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small" 
        onclick="add()">Add</button>
   </div>
 </div><!-- CLOSE ROW -->
  

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@materializecss/materialize@1.1.0/dist/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

I moved the code, which applies the CSS into `applyCSS` and then call it once in the DOMContentLoaded event listener and also each time the add function is called.

Comment: Thanks so much. So clear now you pointed it out.